# How do I put an iap on sale?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I have am working with android studio and google play, how do I lower the price of an in app purchase temporarily? I have tried to create coupons through the google play console. But these discount the purchase 100%. I only want to offer $1 off.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. [See meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561)

Comment: Where else can I ask

Comment: How is this off topic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can edit the price to be 1$ lower than the original one then change it back when you don't want to offer it on sale (in your developer console).